# Google app script to conditional format cell border

Tags: google-sheets, formatting, conditional-statements

Sorry to ask dumb question.
But I really need help
I have a google sheet with 26 columns and 96 raws. I want to change the cell border thickness if cell contain text which is same to Z6 cell value. Is there a way to write a google app script code for this.

I tried this code but failed

```
function formatting() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Chart');
 var range = sheet.getRange("A1:Z100")
 var ruleRed = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
.whenFormulaSatisfied("=$Z$6")
.setBackground("green")
.build();
```

}

PlEASE HELP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Several things:

- The correct formula for conditional formatting would be:
  `"=A1=$Z$6"`
- The correspoding request in Apps Script including the necessary setting of ranges would be:
    `var ruleRed = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule() .whenFormulaSatisfied("=A1=$Z$6") .setBackground("green") .setRanges([range]) .build();`
- After creating a conditional rule, you need to apply to the sheet, e.g. `sheet.setConditionalFormatRules([ruleRed]);`

**However**

- Borders cannot be formatted in scope of conditional formatting, you need to take another approach
- You can use the Apps Script method [setBorder()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbordertop,-left,-bottom,-right,-vertical,-horizontal)
- To set borders as required in Apps Script, you need to

  - retrieve the value of `Z6`
  - Loop through your range comparing all values to `Z6`
  - Assign the border to each cell fulfilling the condition

**Sample for border formatting and conditional formatting with Apps Script:**

```js
function formatting() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Chart');
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:Z100")
  //border formatting 
  var value = sheet.getRange("Z6").getValue();
  var values = range.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
    for (var j = 0; j < values.length; j++){
      if (values[i][j] == value){
        range.getCell(i+1, j+1).setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false);
      }
    }
  }
  //conditional formatting 
  var ruleRed = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .whenFormulaSatisfied("=A1=$Z$6")
  .setBackground("green")
  .setRanges([range])
  .build();
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules([ruleRed]);
}
```

Comment: ziganotschka is there a way to increase the thickness of the formula satisfied cell

Comment: If you use [setBorder(top, left, bottom, right, vertical, horizontal, color, style) ](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbordertop,-left,-bottom,-right,-vertical,-horizontal,-color,-style), you can specify the [style](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/border-style),  e.g.  `SOLID_THICK`.